# Function in Windows that behaves similarly to mkstemp(char* template)

Tags: c, windows, temporary-files

I am looking for some direction in finding a Windows function that acts similarly to

```
mkstemp(char*)
```

does in Linux, i.e., creates unique filename, opens file, and returns file descriptor. I have come across _mktemp_s, but that only incorporates a small part of what I need. Any suggestions/information in the implementation of a Windows style mkstemp() function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following answer implements what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76880432/11398236

Answer (score 1):

If WINAPI is permitted then the function [`GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does almost everything required, with the exception that it does not return a file descriptor. This function could be wrapped in a function to achieve the exact behaviour required.